# Item Table takes forever to load in Dynamics NAV 2013

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

**Test Environment:**

CPU: Intel Core i5 7th Gen (2.71GHz - 4 Logical Processors)
RAM: 12 GB (Free 6 GB)
HDD: 1 TB (Free 700 GB for SQL and NAV)
NAV: 7.0.33781 (2013)
SQL: 2008 SP1
OS: Windows 10 Pro

Note: This is the System where both SQL and NAV system are running together for test purposes. This happens in Live server environment also.

**Problem:** 
Inside the NAV RTC, every page related to Item Table (with no customization) take too much time to load the records. This includes Drill-down pages, Assist Edit Pages and List Pages. This does not happen when navigating through single records (ie: Next and Previous actions) on Item Card page.

**Observation:** 
When loading above said slow-down pages, the CPU performance monitor indicates about 90% usage taken by MSSQLSERVER itself.

**Experiments:** 
 - Taken out the Item Table (TableID: 27) to a fresh DB (Demo DB of NAV)
   and works like a charm since less data.
 - Imported Item table and related pages from a fresh DB (Demo) to this
   issue causing DB but nothing went okay.
 - SQL SELECT * FROM query with no filters and with all the columns
   loads within 0.1 seconds of execution time.

**Extra Specifications:** 
Item Master has 18000 Records in total with no customized fields or newly created fields/flowfields. Neither no codes on Pages' OnOpen triggers nor in table code.

Comment: It's likely the calculation of factboxes' data or flowfields that slows down the page. Did you try to remove all of these from the page? SELECT * FROM Item won't show this, since it won't load all related data displayed in the page, and a large portion of it is calculated based on heavy tables like Value Entry and Item Ledger Entry.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your reply. I understand the facts but I don't have any customized flowfields sadly. Cannot trace the issue since.

Comment: Performance issues can appear on a page without any customization. There have been some hotfixes around this area recently. This one, for example: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2831582/you-experience-slow-performance-when-you-open-a-page-that-use-flowfiel Are you still experiencing the performance problem on the latest platform build / application cumulative update?

Comment: That's a great one I think. I was wondering if I can have a hot fix. Now I think I may have to go for a hot fix. This is the RTM and I think you're correct here.